# Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'nextcloud.oc_appconfig' doesn't exist

Tags: php

I downloaded this open source project named Next cloud, this is the link
[nextcloud](https://github.com/nextcloud/server)

I installed wampserver on my windows 10, i run the project i got this screen
[image]

Ps: my database configuration is

```
database user:root
database password: no passwort
database name: files
database host: localhost
```

when i click submit i get this error message

```
Error while trying to initialise the database: An exception occurred while executing a query: 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'files.oc_appconfig' doesn't exist
```

any solution please??

Comment: The error is saying that there's a missing database table. Make sure you've followed their installation guide correctly. If you have and still have this issue, please reach out to their support. We're here to help you sort out specific issues you might have with _your_ code. It's not a support helpdesk for third party software. When you do reach out to them, you should also mention what version of PHP/MySQL/Nextcloud you're using and explain step by step what you did up to this point.